# Month name of date field in Access database from external application (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, oledb

I want to populate a drop down list at runtime in C#. I have a Date/Time field (e.g., 01/05/2000) in an Access 2003 database. I want to have the month name (i.e. January, February, ...) in the drop down list at runtime.

```
SELECT DISTINCT MonthName(Month(DATE_OF_BOOKING)) AS MNTH 
    FROM TRAVEL_DETAILS WHERE YEAR(DATE_OF_BOOKING)='2008'
```

The above query works fine while I'm running it from Access directly,
but when I'm trying to run it from an `OledbCommand` object in C# it says

> Undefined function 'MonthName' in expression.

Comment: if its working in access why dont you make a Stored procedure of the query ...(just a thought)

Comment: For performance reasons, I'd suggest your WHERE clause should be `WHERE DATE_OF_BOOKING BETWEEN #1/1/2008# AND #12/31/2008#`. I don't know of your OLEDB interface needs to use the Jet/ACE date delimiters or if you can use single quotes and it will convert. The point is that using the Year() function won't be able to use an index on that field (assuming there is one).

Answer (score 2):

Text from social msdn [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/5cee755a-e1ba-4e3c-8705-63685224c890):

> Custom user-written VBA functions as
>   well as many built-in VBA language
>   functions are executed by Microsoft
>   Access when embedded in a SQL query.
>   Unfortunately the functions available
>   to the Jet database engine are limited
>   (when executed via ADO, ADO.NET,
>   etc.). You can find a list of those
>   available in the following MS KB
>   article:

[How to configure Jet 4.0 to prevent unsafe functions from running in Access 2003.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294698/)

EDIT: Use Format() method.

```
SELECT DISTINCT  format(DATE_OF_BOOKING,'MMMM') 
   AS MNTH FROM TRAVEL_DETAILS WHERE YEAR(DATE_OF_BOOKING)='2008'
```

Comment: Format will also allow you to choose a number, short or full month name according to the number of Ms you use.

Answer (score 1):

[MonthName](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MonthName-Function-c64bcf54-2534-45bc-acef-de80f4a959c4) is one of the many Access functions that was not supported by the ODBC and OLEDB drivers for the original "Jet" database engine, i.e.

`Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}` for ODBC, or
`Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` for OLEDB

but it *is* supported by the drivers for the newer "ACE" database engine

`Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}` for ODBC, or
`Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` for OLEDB

[Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920)
[Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)