# Undefined Function: MONTHNAME - OLEDB

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, rdlc

I have this function in an RDLC report. I built the string in Ms Access (as I'm pretty bad at just writing them straight out). It works in MS Access, and it works in vis studio on my PC. It also works when compiled into EXE.

However on one laptop it is coming up with

> Undefined Function MonthName in expression

```
SELECT MonthName(Month(tblpack.cycledate)) AS MonthDate, Year(tblpack.cycledate) AS YearDate, Sum(tblpack.weeksinpack) AS SumOfweeksinpack, Month(tblpack.cycledate) AS MonthOrder
FROM tblpatient INNER JOIN tblpack ON tblpatient.patientid = tblpack.patientid
WHERE (((tblpack.iscommunity)=True) AND ((tblpatient.over5med)=True) AND ((tblpack.isrepat)=True) AND ((tblpack.cycledate) Between ? And ?) AND ((tblpack.packeduser) Is Not Null)) OR (((tblpack.iscommunity)=True) 
AND ((tblpatient.over5med)=True) AND ((tblpack.isconcession)=True) AND ((tblpack.cycledate) Between ? And ?) AND ((tblpack.packeduser) Is Not Null))
GROUP BY MonthName(Month(tblpack.cycledate)), Year(tblpack.cycledate), Month(tblpack.cycledate)
ORDER BY MonthName(Month(tblpack.cycledate)), Year(tblpack.cycledate)
```

I can't understand why it works on one computer and not another when the string is the same and the connection is the same as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `MonthName` function with ADO.NET since the sandboxed function only available for queries running inside Access application session. [This article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5cee755a-e1ba-4e3c-8705-63685224c890/ms-access-function-monthname-causing-error-in-vb?forum=adodotnetdataproviders) described Access behavior related to your problem:

> Custom user-written VBA functions as well as many built-in VBA
>   language functions are executed by Microsoft Access when embedded in a
>   SQL query. Unfortunately the functions available to the Jet database
>   engine are limited (when executed via ADO, ADO.NET, etc.)

As a workaround, you can use `Format` function with `MMMM` format string to display full month name:

```
SELECT Format(tblpack.cycledate, 'MMMM') AS MonthDate,
       Year(tblpack.cycledate) AS YearDate, Sum(tblpack.weeksinpack) AS SumOfweeksinpack, 
       Month(tblpack.cycledate) AS MonthOrder
FROM tblpatient 
INNER JOIN tblpack ON tblpatient.patientid = tblpack.patientid
WHERE (((tblpack.iscommunity)=True) 
      AND ((tblpatient.over5med)=True) 
      AND ((tblpack.isrepat)=True) 
      AND ((tblpack.cycledate) Between ? And ?) 
      AND ((tblpack.packeduser) Is Not Null)) 
      OR (((tblpack.iscommunity)=True) 
      AND ((tblpatient.over5med)=True) 
      AND ((tblpack.isconcession)=True) 
      AND ((tblpack.cycledate) Between ? And ?) 
      AND ((tblpack.packeduser) Is Not Null))
GROUP BY Format(tblpack.cycledate, 'MMMM'), Year(tblpack.cycledate), Month(tblpack.cycledate)
ORDER BY Format(tblpack.cycledate, 'MMMM'), Year(tblpack.cycledate)
```

References:

[How to configure Jet 4.0 to prevent unsafe functions from running in Access 2003](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/294698/how-to-configure-jet-4-0-to-prevent-unsafe-functions-from-running-in-a)

[month name from date field in c#.net from access database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720788/month-name-from-date-field-in-c-net-from-access-database)

Comment: thanks Tetsuya, 
My only question is: Why does my query work on two computers but not the third?

Comment: Are those PCs have exactly same Access configuration & version? This problem often occur when using MSJet engine (don't know much if ACE engine suffers similar issue), different configuration settings may have different results.

Comment: ok thanks, that explains it. Maybe it is the access version.  I've changed to your query, thanks for the help! :)